# Plot roots of polynomials

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, data, simulation

I am a newbie with Mathematica.

I would like to simulate/plot the distribution of the roots of both the polynomials and the derivatives of polynomials. In particular, I would like plot the distribution of the roots of $P_n(z)$ and $Q_n (z)$.

---

I am trying to use the syntax:

```
ReIm@Flatten[Values@Solve[Product[(x - i), {i, dataND}] == 0, x, Complexes]]
```

where `dataND` is a random set on the complex plane or circle but it cannot be done. I can only plot the roots for $P_n(z)$ with

```
dataND = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], myseed]
```

but that's not what I want. I would really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Please reduce this problem further to one that is related to Mathematica, rather than the underlying mathematics or algorithm, if you can.

Comment: Please provide the code that you use to obtain the `dataND` that you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is not entirely clear, I believe that defining `dataND` as something like

```
SeedRandom[1492];
myseed = 100;
dataND = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], myseed]*
         Exp[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, myseed] I];
```

may produce the desired plot.

```
sol = Flatten@Values@Solve[Product[(x - i), {i, dataND}] == 0, x];
ComplexListPlot[sol, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: @user52523 I fixed a typo in my answer which should address the concern in your second comment.

Comment: @user52523 Please provide the code that gives the gammas.

Comment: @user52523 I do not know how I can help you without knowing how gamma is defined.

Comment: @user52523 `GammaDistribution[a, b]` depends on two parameters.  What values are you choosing?  Also, if my answer adequately addresses the question you originally posted, please accept it now.